# A tutorial on adding search to an Eclipse RCP program

Tags: eclipse, search, rcp

Could some one point me to a tutorial on how to work with the Eclipse search plug-in with custom views in an Eclipse RCP program.  I have tried searching google for one, but I have found to have the word "search" in your search phrase you might as well not have it there.

I have tried the phrase "Eclipse RCP search" "Eclipse RCP search tutorial" "Eclipse RCP search plug-in" and none of my results are about the search plug-in (maybe a suggested search phrase if one can not suggest a good tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Implementing your custom search is not that hard. The best is to look into other plugins to see how they implemented the search.
To get you started I recommed the Task-Search from Mylyn - very easy to adopt.

Just donwload the sources from Mylyn and look at the bundle

```
org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search
```

HTH Tom

Answer (score 0):

You may start here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_a_Search_dialog%3F
It is not strictly related to RCP development, but I think it applies to that also.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a good article about search in Eclipse.

Also see [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=104561) and [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=163527) bugs

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you need 5 classes to implement following interfaces:

- ISearchQuery
- ISearchResult
- SearchResultEvent
- ISearchPage
- ISearchResultPage

Furthermore the last 2 implementations need to be registered as extension points:

- org.eclipse.search.searchPages
- org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages

For a detailed tutorial how to glue this stuff together [read this article](http://codeandme.blogspot.de/2015/07/a-custom-search-provider.html)