# How to create a search view using Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am doing a Eclipse plug-in project to implement an IDE like Eclipse.

I want to create a view that contains a text box and a button, where the user can come and enter some text and once he presses the search button, my IDE should search a interface (created by me) which contains standard functions, variables and keywords. After completing the search the matched keywords or function should be displayed in that view.

And once the results are displayed, the user should be able to double-click the particular text, when the user clicks this text should be inserted into the active editor that is opened.

Can anyone help me to implement this functionality using Eclipse plugins? If you have any tutorials for implementing this search view, can you please send me the link for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plug into the Search support already in Eclipse, see [Search Support](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/search.htm).

Also see similar question [A tutorial on adding search to an Eclipse RCP program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628234/713646)